# Defining a Func with flexible dimension in C#

Tags: c#, func

In `C#`, I would like a method that returns a `Func`, but where the expression of the `Func` depends on some input-given dimension.

For instance, suppose I want the function `F` to always return the product of its variables, but that the number of variables can vary. What I have done so far is the following:

```
    public static Func<double[],double> DefineFunction()
    {
        Func<double[], double> F = x => Prod(x);

        return F;
    }

    public static double Prod(double[] vector)
    {
        double result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i<vector.Length; i++)
        {
            result *= vector[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Then I can define a function that outputs the product of e.g. three arguments as follows:

```
        Func<double[], double> G = DefineFunction();
        double test = G(new double[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        Console.WriteLine(test);
```

My question is if this is the best way to do it. My approach uses another whole method just to define `F`, which seems like overkill. Let me mention that it needs not always be the product, but always some homogeneous expression that easily generalizes across dimensions.

Comment: `F = x => x.Aggregate(1d, (a, b) => a*b)`

Comment: You don't need `DefineFunction()`, you could just do `Func<double[], double> G = Prod;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code allready provided works. But as allready mentioned, Aggregate does exactly what you want.

```
Console.WriteLine(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4}.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
```

Outputs "10"

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned and posted elsewhere, the Enumerable class has a number of methods that allow you to **apply a func across a collection**, Aggregate being an example. However, following your line of reasoning of trying to use Func and roll your own apply, something like the below is how you would structure it:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //define your general apply function
        Func<double[], Func<double, double, double>, double, double> G = (vars, func, init) =>
        {
            double result = init;
            foreach (var t in vars)
            {
                result = func(result,t);
            }

            return result;
        };

        //here is a product example    
        double test = G(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, (prev, x) => prev * x, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(test);

        //here is an addition example
        test = G(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, (prev, x) => prev + x, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(test);            
    }   
}
```

In the above, you can pass in any func or expression such as: `(prev, x) => prev * x` and an array of doubles, and an init value (above 1 for product and 0 for addition).

Comment: This is precisely what the `.Aggregate` LINQ operator does already.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure of the use case, but I think .Aggregate(...) would be another good solution. I was trying to follow his original line of reasoning to show how func can be structured more generally without the intermediate method. But the .Aggregate would be another good answer to post.

Comment: I would suggest that you make that point in your answer. It would then tick all the boxes in my mind.